# In coffee-script whats the differences between these two ways of creating backbone models, views etc

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am currently looking at coffee-script because the syntax is greate and easier to write/understand than pure javascript. However I found that tutorials using backbone and coffee-script show that the way to create a model is as follows:

```
class User extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: ->
    alert 'start'
```

This looks all nice, but when using `extends` it compiles rather strangely... I understand this is coffee-script's way of making classes work in javascript.

```
(function() {
  var User,
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

    User = (function(_super) {

    __extends(User, _super);

    function User() {
      return User.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    User.prototype.initialize = function() {
      return alert('start');
    };

    return User;

  })(Backbone.Model);

}).call(this);
```

but if you use:

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend
    initialize: ->
        alert 'start'
```

that compiles a lot better (more like how I would write it):

```
(function() {
  var User;

  User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      return alert('start');
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

Can anyone explain to me the differences in the ways of creating a model class and why the first method is used more often in tutorials when the second one compiles more like how I would create a model in pure javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two methods are functionally equivalent, with no significant difference in how they work. There are some implementation differences, sure, but the end result is the same.

The real difference, and why you see the larger code generation from the coffeescript `extends` keyword, is that when you call `Backbone.Model.extend`, you are calling Backbone's version of the same code that CoffeeScript produces. It's encapsulated within Backbone's `extend` method, but it's largely similar in how it works and why.

The only reason you see the CoffeeScript `extends` used everywhere, is because you're looking at CoffeeScript examples. Honestly, that's it. There's no benefit to doing it one way or the other. It's just that CoffeeScript says you should use the `extends` keyword so people do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Backbone, but I would think that `Backbone.Model.extend` only exists to avoid such longish and complicated stuff as the CoffeeScript compiles into. But since CoffeeScript provides an "extends" keyword, you're able to go with a nice and clean OOP-ish way and still end up with readable code.

Comment: So why does it still work with the nicer OOP-ish way when Backbone objects have the extend function built in? I am finding it hard to understand.. is there much of a difference between the two ways.

Comment: No, the difference seems not to be notable. In fact, Backbone's extend method will do pretty much the same stuff, so it just hides a bunch of code from you - just as CoffeeScript does. But since Backbone is Open Source, you can go and check what exactly Model.extend() does: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js